# AngularJS: How to bind-html-unsafe to an attribute?

Tags: angularjs

What is the correct way to make an unsafe bind to an attribute? In my case, I get undesired HTML entities in the title-attribute:

```
<a href="..." title="Something &quot;goes bad&quot;">Link</a>
```

(Angular 1.1.5)

Comment: be more specific about source of title and problem as it is now

Comment: I think my question is clear enough. I need to force the same behavior as the directive ng-bind-html-unsafe has, only for an attribute.

Comment: no you haven't....it displays properly in browser. Can think you've been clear enough with one sentence question that so far hasn't made sense...but won't get a lot of help around here without defining issues in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&quot;` is how `"` is escaped in HTML (and XML) attributes, there's no way around it. It will display correctly on the page, however. Attribute contents aren't parsed as HTML so there's no need for an equivalent to `bind-html-unsafe`.

Comment: It's wrong, in the database stands: "&quot;", after the Output it should be "", but it is still a &quot;. It is due to Angular's $sanitize Service.

Comment: Or, if they are not parsed as HTML, we maybe need a way to display " there, and maybe this question has just nothing to do with Angular?..